# Flutter inspector stuck on "Installing Dev tools"

Tags: flutter

My flutter inspector in android studio is stuck on "Installing Dev tools"

[image]

it worked before, Today when I opened it, it did not work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The fact is that the IDE seems to recently have started using embedding devtools in the inspector tab. I have my Flutter version up to date and my Android Studio's version is 4.1. Until the problem gets solved I have three possible solutions:

- One is invalidating caches by going to File > Invalidate Caches > Restart > Invalidate and Restart.
- Another one would be (for Windows) running on the Android Studio console:

> flutter.bat pub global activate devtools

> flutter.bat pub global run devtools

- And the third one (the one that worked for me): go to File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks  > Flutter > Experiments … and there you should uncheck “Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspector tool window”. That should allow you to use devtools locally instead of the embedded ones.

[image: Image that shows the process]

And by the way, in order to use Devtools you should first make sure your application is running ;)

As I said before, they seem to be already fixing the problem. They made other changes to DevTools management that should solve the issue. For more information you should go to: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5032

Answer (score 11):

By running `File > Invalid Caches / Restart...`, the problem was fixed

Answer (score 1):

There's a Github issue for this https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5032

Answer (score 0):

I breaked it

`flutter doctor` resuming installation process

Answer (score 0):

what I did

Closed the Android Studio and Opened it again, Run the project, and waited for **2 mins**, this time it has shown.